# iOS trace in XCode 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

I'm working on an iOS project and am trying to find out how I can go about getting a trace of all the functions that are being called when I do something on my emulator.

The reason I'm looking for something like this is because I'm not quite sure what listeners are being triggered upon some of my actions on the emulator.

Cheers and thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a breakpoint?

I'd read [Apple's guide to debugging](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW1) first, but just click the sidebar to the left of the line of code you want to stop at, and a blue indicator will appear. Then when you run the app, it will break when that line of code is hit. From there you can look at the stack using the acessory view on the bottom (where NSLog outputs, there are two views... one has the stack trace).

Comment: I do know about breakpoints -- but I'm not quite sure where to set them in this case -- am working on a larger project to which I don't know all the moving parts of.

Comment: @sparkFinder I would guess you're going to have to poke around the code, set some trial breakpoints and slowly figure out the moving parts of this system. If you had a more clear question someone might be able to offer a shortcut. i.e. "what method gets called when you touch up inside a table view" and then someone could suggest the `UITableViewDelegate`'s `-(void)tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

When your debugging a large code base with multiple listeners, it's sometimes tough to figure out where to put the right break point.  Another option is to log to see all the listeners that are triggered.

However, a big issue with NSLog is you'll end up littering your code and then eventually want to remove it before shipping.

Ideally, you could:

1. Add logging/tracing throughout your code
2. Enable/Disable the logging at levels
3. Optionally turn it off for retail shipping.

I have logging macros which offers those which I pieced together from others and I responded to this SO article and pasted in the implementation.

[What logging solutions to use while log-debugging objective-C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294215/what-logging-solutions-to-use-while-log-debugging-objective-c-code/7294231#7294231)

Hope that helps