# XCode: Stop at BreakPoint for certain amount of time and the move on?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, coding-style, breakpoints

So I have a bunch of break points set that help me track the progress of my iOS app -- and I have to do a continue (a three key shortcut) while paying attention to my app. Is there anyway to have the break points be stopped at, for, say 2 seconds and then automatically move on? It would be really, really helpful.

Thanks and Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of.  But, another way to "track the progress" of your app is to use logging.  One problem with logging however is you litter your code with logging that you want to rip out before shipping.

One alternative is to have a logging functions/macros where you can condition out as levels and even turn off.

Here's my related post on a logging class that does that:

[What logging solutions to use while log-debugging objective-C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294215/what-logging-solutions-to-use-while-log-debugging-objective-c-code/7294231#7294231)